# Trouble clearing react.useState with clear button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, use-state

I am finding it difficult to clear this file input that I am setting to setImportFile useState. This is the useState I declared

```
const [importFile, setImportFile] = React.useState<File | null>();
const [fileError, setFileError] = React.useState<string>("");
```

I clear two useState variables in this const method but only one gets cleared which is setFileError.

```
  const clearModal = () => {
        setImportFile(null);
        setFileError("");
    };
```

I use setImportFile in this method

```
 const onChangeImportFile = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setImportFile(e.currentTarget.files ? e.currentTarget.files[0] : null);
        setSaving(true);
    };
```

This is my render in which I use the clear button and only the error would clear out but the file input will not clear out. I want to empty everything in the modal

```
 <Form.Control
     type="file"
     accept='.csv, .xls, .xlsx'
     required
     className="primary mb-3"
     name=""
     onChange={onChangeImportFile}
/>
  <Button variant="secondary" onClick={clearModal} > Clear </Button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to pass the state value to the Form.Control, to make it controlled (otherwise it's not getting its value from the state).

```
<Form.Control
  type="file"
  accept='.csv, .xls, .xlsx'
  required
  className="primary mb-3"
  name=""
  value={importFile}
  onChange={onChangeImportFile}
/>
```

Comment: That wont work because type file is not assignable to type string.

Comment: Where do you have a type string? Fom.Control has `type="file"` and your state `importFile` has a File. On `onChangeImportFile` you're setting the state with a File `setImportFile(e.currentTarget.files ? e.currentTarget.files[0] : null);`. Have you tried it and it's not working?

Comment: I ended up using userRef to reference the input button and clear it when called

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to set `File | null` as *SetStateAction* will be set to `undefined`.

Try this:

```
const [importFile, setImportFile] = React.useState<File>();
setImportFile(undefined);
```